# meteor run android-device isn't working - Error: failed to deploy to device, no devices found

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

My app works perfectly fine on the **Android Emulator**, but as soon as I try to run the command `meteor run android-device` it throws the following error **ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.**

I have tried to run several apps including Meteor's official **Local Market App**, no luck yet.

**USB Debugging** is enabled on the both devices and they were connected to my mac via USB port. Before **Meteor 1.2** update, everything was working fine with the same devices.

Can anyone advice me on this please? I've looked up online, couldn't find any recent solutions.

**UPDATE** it was rather ridiculously silly problem, that was fixed as soon as I used the original charging cable instead of fancy portable cables...

Comment: did you install the drivers correctly? try restarting adb

Comment: @jcesarmobile I believe I've installed all the required drivers, following the official guide (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-Android-on-Mac]) in terms of **adb**, I've restarted it, but still no good.

Comment: I mean the USB drivers for the device.

Comment: @jcesarmobile, I'm not sure what drivers for the device do you mean? as I've tried two different modern devices with up to date software. Besides, everything was working fine with the same devices before **Meteor 1.2** update.

Comment: I meant the device USB drivers, or google USB drivers. But if it worked before then that's not the problem. Good to know that you already solver it using another cable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was rather ridiculously silly problem, that was fixed as soon as I used the original charging cable instead of fancy portable cables...